# One has to many relationship Foreach Undefined variable in LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

Hi guys I want to foreach the indicator products of specific user using one has to many relationship my code seems right but it's having an undefined variable I don't know why. I searched all troubleshoots but it can't be solved. Hope u guys help me. Thanks.

**User model**

```php
public function indicator(){
    // this is one to many relationship
    return $this->hasMany(Indicator::class);
}
```

**Indicator model**

```php
class Indicator extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'indicators';
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamp = true;  

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

**HomeController**

```php
public function index()
{
    $indicators =User::find(1)->indicator;
    return view('pages.index', compact('indicators'));
}
```

**pages.index**

```php
@include('layouts.template')

@include('main.carousel')
@include('main.cards')
@include('main.trades')
@include('main.pillars')
@include('main.services')
@include('partials.footer')

@foreach ($indicators as $indicator)
    <h4>{{$indicator->indicator_img}}</h4>
@endforeach
```

**Error**

> "Undefined variable: indicators (View: /opt/lampp/htdocs/ecommerceindicator/resources/views/pages/index.blade.php)"

but if i run the php artisan tinker on my terminal using this App\User::find(2)->indicator i can get the datas form my tables

Answer (score 0):

Specify the foreign key and local key in the relation. 
like this
`return $this->hasOne('App\Phone', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');`
for more details  `https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse`

Comment: hi i can already fetch the data on my terminal using php artisan tinker

using this App\User::find(2)->indicator
but on my pages.index it says undefined variable

Answer (score 0):

this might work for you ..

```
public function index()
{
    $indicators =User::find(1)->indicator;
    $data = [];
    $data['indicators'] = $indicators;

    return view('pages.index', $data); // or return view('pages.index')->with($data);
}
```

Comment: nothing seems working hmm is the error related to my other controllers? or web.php?

Comment: nothing seems working hmm is the error related to my other controllers? or web.php?

Comment: yep i think its fine i think the error is at the web php or my controllers i dont know :(

Comment: could you try passing a dummy variable with a string value like `$dummyVar = 'sample';` in the view and try displaing it using blade .. `{{ $dummyVar }}`

Comment: i try to use this it also not get the variable this is from my another controller i just copy paste it my Home controller

use App\User;
use App\Indicator;

    public function index()
{
    $indicators = Indicator::orderBy('created_at')->paginate(8);
        return view('pages.index')->with('indicators', $indicators);
}
}

Comment: i also try this nothing work hmmmmm

{
        $dummyVar = 'sample'
        return view('pages.index',)->with('dummyVar', $dummyVar);
    }

Comment: you got the answer mate ?

Comment: hi bro yes the problem is in the web.php are there two roots that has the same url

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys i already solved the error the problem is in the web.php thanks for answering my question

```
Route::get('/homepage', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/homepage', 'PagesController@index');
Route::resource('indicators', 'IndicatorsController');
Route::resource('ebooks', 'EbooksController');
Route::get('/addIndicator', 'PagesController@addindicator');
```

the problem is the url is the same so i changed it

```
Route::get('/homepage', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/indi', 'PagesController@index1');
Route::resource('indicators', 'IndicatorsController');
Route::resource('ebooks', 'EbooksController');
Route::get('/addIndicator', 'PagesController@addindicator');
```